# Grouped TableView

Tags: iphone, slider, switch-statement, tableview

[image]

I want to create a table view which looks like this image! Who can tell me an example or say how can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a good tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) on customising a grouped UITableView, although it does assume that you are proficient with an image editor to create the various custom images.

Answer (score 7):

Create a UITableView and set the style to UITableViewStyleGrouped (you can do this programmatically or in the IB).

Then you want 2 sections, the first has 3 rows and the second has 1 row.

You should probably just look in the documentation for UITableView and check out the same code there to get started, but this is the basic format.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your init method in your UITableView class

```
    [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some something similar using grouped static uitableview for creating setting page take a look here [Xcode 6 Tutorial Grouped UITableView using Swift](http://shrikar.com/blog/2014/12/27/xcode-6-tutorial-grouped-uitableview/)