# ios settings screen user interface

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to make a setting screen in my application like the settings that exists inside of the iPhone. When clicking on settings, we see the different sections with rounded edges, all white, some of hte options have arrows, some are on/off buttons.

How did Apple acheive this? Is it a `UITableView`? Is there any documentation on how to make the options look similar? Or is there any open source example of Apple's settings screen implementation?

I would like to make a settings screen with similar functionality, hence I wanted to know how it was achieved for the settings screen. Unfortunately, could not find this with searching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a grouped UITableView.

[Grouped TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299539/grouped-tableview)

You can pretty much build a similar app to Apple's settings app very easily, specially if you use Storyboards and static cells.

You will need to set their accessory types and push a new view if a cell has a certain accessory type. At any rate it's not hard to build one, even if you go the ancient way (pre iOS 5). You can build something like that really fast nowadays.

Answer (score 5):

It's a `UITableView` with `style` set to `UITableViewStyleGrouped`.

The cells with the arrows have `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` for the `accessoryType`.
The on/off buttons are called Switches they can also be used as a cell accessory

Answer (score 1):

The UI for the Settings app is basically a set of **UITableViewControllers** with a "grouped" style. If you haven't worked with tables, you should take some time to read the "*[Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)*". It covers everything you need to know about creating and using tables.